# Issue with controls alignment in dynamically created Frame

Tags: delphi, alignment, frame

My program uses dynamically created frames and sometimes I get an issue that their controls are improperly aligned.

I use my own container control inherited from `TPanel`, but the same problem can be found when using the `GridPanel` as well.

Here is the source of a [test](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6JcVXKk0xuddkdycU5oQjMwSHM) program that reproduces the problem (with compiled exe).

The key code snippets:

in the main form:

```
//creating Frame from the main form
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  f := TFrame2.Create(Self);
  f.Parent := Self;
end;
```

in the frame:

```
//constructor of the Frame
constructor TFrame2.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  Edit1.Clear;// the problem appears
end;
```

The frame and all its controls are aligned and must have the width of the main form, but `Edit1` and `ComboBox1` are visually not aligned until you resize the form manually (Sending `WM_SIZE` has no effect).

But if you comment the `Edit1.Clear` line everything will work fine from the program start. This code is not specific for the error and you can enter here e.g. `ComboBox1.Items.Add('')` etc.

If the frame is created statically or the `GridPanel` is changed to `Panel` the problem disappears.

I have made a new [test2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6JcVXKk0xudNEFpNDQtQ2dNams) version thanks to @quasoft, it works better - now the controls are horizontally aligned proper but vertically combobox is not in the right place that can be seen by changing the form size.

Comment: If you just replace `Edit1.Clear` with `Edit1.Text := ''` it works as you would expect

Comment: I see you project and all is fine , and as @quasoft say jut replace `Edit1.Clear;`

Comment: *"If the frame is created statically"* check the frame's `WindowHandle` in the `TFrame2.Create` in both cases (static and dynamic). You might want to init your "Handle dependent" controls in the Frame `CreateWnd` handler, where you know the controls have valid window handle. (I can't test this right now).

Comment: Yes, there are no alignment problems with the frames created statically. For the frames created dynamically I use HandleAllocated and HandleNeeded functions to make sure that the handle is valid (e.g. when sending messages). Isn't that enough?

Answer (score 3):

### Quick fix:

The quick solution to your problem is to use `Text` property of `TEdit`, instead of the `Clear` method - as already said, replacing `Edit1.Clear` with `Edit1.Text := ''`.

### Understanding the problem

But you need to understand this problem better if you plan to use frames in Delphi in the long term, or they will haunt you while you sleep (joking).

The real problem is that you are modifying the state of the frame before a `Parent` has been assigned to it.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  f := TFrame2.Create(Self);    // <--- Your text edit is cleared inside
  f.Parent := Self;             // <--- Your frame is attached to the form here
end;
```

Doing so does not allow the `TGridPanel` component to take in account the width, height and position of parent when calculating the size of its columns and rows.

Using `Text` property works, because the property setter does not change the text of the control directly, but sends a message for the purpose to the message queue:

> Except from Controls.pas:
>
> ```
> ...
> procedure TControl.SetTextBuf(Buffer: PChar);
> begin
>   Perform(WM_SETTEXT, 0, Longint(Buffer));
>   Perform(CM_TEXTCHANGED, 0, 0);
> end;
>
> procedure TControl.SetText(const Value: TCaption);
> begin
>   if GetText <> Value then SetTextBuf(PChar(Value));
> end;
> ...
> ```

Which in effect, causes the text to actually change after you have assigned the `Parent` of the frame - as the message queue will be processed a little bit after the form create method completes.

`Clear` method on the other hand directly changes the text:

> Excerpt from StdCtrls.pas:
>
> ```
> ...
> procedure TCustomEdit.Clear;
> begin
>   SetWindowText(Handle, '');
> end;
> ...
> ```

### A better solution

As you already learned, the quick fix works only in the specific example you provided.

A better solution is to create an `Init` method in your frame and call this method from the main form **after** `Parent` has been assigned:

**Your frame:**

```
procedure TFrame2.Init;
begin
  Edit1.Clear;
  ComboBox1.Items.Add('Foo Bar');
end;
```

**Your main form:**

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  f := TFrame2.Create(Self);
  f.Parent := Self;             // <--- Your frame is attached to the form here
  f.Init;                       // <--- Calls initialization code of frame
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, I tested the method you offered, for this synthetic test it works fine, for more complex cases it works better, but not perfectly. Omitting the questions of how clearing the edit's text or adding an item to the combobox can affect their position, why overriding SetParent doesn't work or why sending WM_SIZE to the proper handle has no effect, I can say that some issues stay unresolved e.g when aligned controls are created dynamically in the dynamically created frame.

Comment: @Molochnik - expecting a solution for a non-presented problem is not realistic. I suggest you to ask a new question with a corresponding test case.